# How are standard library exception bad_alloc thrown and std::abort called when there is no standard header included?

Tags: c++, exception

I noticed that if `new` fails to find free-store memory to allocate, it will throw the standard library exception `bad_alloc`.

And in my understanding, if we don't catch an exception, `std::abort` will be called to terminate the program.

So I tried the following code (without `#include` anything):

```cpp
int main()
{
    int* p = new int[99999999999999];  // or any number that is sufficiently large
}
```

and the result stated that `abort() has been called`.

I know that [`new` is implicitly declared in each translation unit even if the  header is not included](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

However, in my understanding, if we don't `#include` any standard header, facilities like standard library exception and `std::abort` are not defined.

So, my question is, how are `bad_alloc` thrown and `std::abort` called in the about situation where they are not defined?

Comment: These things only need to be defined at the point whether that exception is thrown or the point where abort is called. They don't have to be defined in **your** code unless you want to use them. I think you are confusing the meaning of defined with 'being included in your program'. Something can be defined in one part of a program but not defined in another.

Comment: The compilers standard runtime library that it links any executable with is allowed to throw exceptions and it can include any header it likes, so the standard library can compile. That's how it can throw the exception - your code doesn't need to know about it for it to be thrown.

Comment: Headers tell the compiler what certain names mean. If a source file doesn't use those names it doesn't need the headers that define them. The file that implements the details of `operator new` needs to know about `std::bad_alloc`, and the code that handles stack unwinding for exceptions needs to know about `std::abort`. The code in the question doesn't use either of those names, so it doesn't need the headers that define them.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that new is implicitly declared in each translation unit even if the header is not included.

`new` is a keyword in C++ and `new int[99999999999999]` is a specific type of an expression, a new-expression. This is intrinsically part of the core language. There is no sense in which this `new` could be declared. It is just a keyword part of a specific syntax construct. It is not a function call or anything like that.

`<new>` declares overloads of `operator new`, which *is* a function that can be declared. `operator new` is however not the same as a new-expression. They both use the keyword `new` and the new-expression typically calls a `operator new` overload, but they are completely different things.

---

Whether or not `std::bad_alloc` has been declared in your translation unit is irrelevant to whether or not the new-expression can throw it. The new-expression is part of the core language and the standard library is also intrinsic part of the language itself, they cannot be strictly separated. It would be completely fine to specify the language in such a way that `std::bad_alloc` is thrown even if no standard library header is included. There doesn't literally have to be some C++ code included from a standard library header containing a throw expression. The compiler can just insert it as required.

However, `std::bad_alloc` here isn't thrown from the new-expression itself. It is thrown from the `operator new` which is implicitly declared and called by the new-expression. If this is implemented in normal C++ code, then the exception type needs only be declared where the actual `throw` expression is placed inside `operator new`'s definition, not where the exception is propagated. The definition of the `operator new` will be typically located in some dynamic library supplied with the standard library implementation.

A better example would be `std::bad_array_new_length` which would be thrown for example by an array-new-expression if the number of elements requested is not a compile-time constant and happens to be negative before conversion to `std::size_t` at runtime. This exception is thrown directly from the new-expression, not the `operator new`, even if no standard library header is included.

---

And similarly, because `std::abort` (and `std::terminate`) are also part of the standard library and so intrinsically part of the language, they can still be called e.g. when an exception is not caught, even if none of the user code includes a standard library header and so no declaration for either function is available in the user translation units.